# Max Heapify code.Starting index 1 instead of 0 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, heapsort

```
def max_heapify(arr, n, i):  

    largest = i
    left = 2*i
    right = 2*i + 1
    while left <= n and arr[left] > arr[largest]:
        largest = left

    while right <= n and arr[right] > arr[largest]:
        largest = right
    if largest != i:
        arr[largest], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[largest]
        print(arr)   
        max_heapify(arr, n, i)

arr=[9, 6, 5, 0, 8, 2, 7, 1,3]  
n = len(arr)
i = int(n/2)  
max_heapify(arr, n, i)
```

The above Max Heapify code is failing because it' starting from Array 0. How can we change it 1?

Comment: Please include the output you're expecting to generate vs the output you are currently seeing.

Comment: @DHerls: Thank you for response. Getting this error 
n= 9,   i= 4
largest= 4
left= 8
right= 9
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5fac3ed03759> in <module>()
     28 i = int(n/2)
     29 print('i=',i)
---> 30 max_heapify(arr, n, i)

<ipython-input-15-5fac3ed03759> in max_heapify(arr, n, i)
     11     largest = left
     12 
---> 13   while right <= n and arr[right] > arr[largest]:
     14    largest = right
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @DHerls:I'm expecting output to be [9, 8, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 0]

Comment: I think that error is caused by your "<= n" in the while loop conditions.  You want just < because n is the length of the array so the max element is n-1

Comment: If I change to <n, n= 9
i= 4
largest= 4
left= 8
right= 9. So if we see 2nd while loop then it's 9 < 9 and  arr[9]>arr[4]. Hereindex starts from 0 . so there is no arr[9].

Answer (score 0):

for an array starting from 0, you will need to compare `left < n` and `right < n` in addition, your initial left and right should be `left = 2 * i + 1` and `right = 2 * i + 2`. To retrieve the max heap, you will also need to call the `max_heapify` from the first parent node all the way down to 0. Finally there is no need for a while loop when you are assured of it happening only once. Here is a working code that returns the results you require

```
def max_heapify(arr, n, i):  

    left = 2*i + 1
    right = 2*i + 2

    if left < n and arr[left] > arr[i]:
        largest = left
    else:
        largest = i

    if right < n and arr[right] > arr[largest]:
        largest = right

    if largest != i:
        arr[largest], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[largest]
        print(arr)   
        max_heapify(arr, n, largest)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr=[9, 6, 5, 0, 8, 2, 7, 1,3]  
    n = len(arr)
    i = int((n-1)/2)  
    for b in reversed(range(0,i)):
        max_heapify(arr, n, b)
```